# How to do ping test for Microsoft bot framework in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I have a Microsoft bot framework deployed in a App Service in Azure and enabled Application Insights for monitoring the bot. I trying to add some ping tests to monitoring the uptime. Since /api/messages endpoint requires a App ID and secret i wanted to know the best approach to ping the bot on frequent interval.

Answer (score 0):

As a Bot is a normal Web Api, you can create another ping action inside messages controller and call that as you would call any other Api method whenever you would want to monitor the up-time. In the action you could send events to App Insights, logging information as required. I would recommend using proper Authentication on this Api for security purposes.